# Angularjs filter exact number

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I have a form that displays dropdown select boxes for states and counties, everything it working ok, except when I choose a state with a single digit, say the number "1" the filter will include the other states that also have number "1" in them.  I need to filter exactly or "true" but not sure how the code should look for that, I'm still learning Angular.

Here's my Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('myController', function($scope) {
  $scope.projects = [{
name: 'First thing',
state: 'CA',
stateID: '1',
county: 'Orange',
countyID: '191'
}, {
name: 'Another Thing',
state: 'CA',
stateID: '1',
county: 'LosAngeles',
countyID: '190'
}, {
name: 'In California',
state: 'CA',
stateID: '1',
county: 'Orange',
countyID: '191'
}, {
name: 'Hey Arizona!',
state: 'Arizona',
stateID: '13',
county: 'Multiple Counties',
countyID: '3178'
},{
name: 'hello Utah',
state: 'Utah',
stateID: '14',
county: 'Utah County',
countyID: '200'
}];

$scope.st_option = [{
state: "California",
stateID: "1"
}, {
state: "Arizona",
stateID: "13"
},{
state: "Utah",
stateID: "14"
}];

$scope.co_option = [{
county: "Orange",
countyID: "191",
co_state_id: "1"
}, {
county: "Multiple Counties",
countyID: "3178",
co_state_id: "13"
}, {
county: "Sonoma",
countyID: "218",
co_state_id: "1"
}, {
county: "Los Angeles",
countyID: "190",
co_state_id: "1"
}, {
county: "Utah County",
countyID: "200",
co_state_id: "14"
}];

$scope.filter = {};
$scope.clearFilter = function() {
$scope.filter = {};
};
});
```

And the View:

```
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='myController'>
<h3>Records: {{(projects|filter:filter).length}} of {{projects.length}}</h3>
<p><input type="text" name="generalSearch" placeholder="Search Project Title" ng-model="filter.name"></p>
<p><select ng-model="filter.stateID" 
      ng-options="item.stateID as item.state for item in st_option"></select>
<select ng-model="filter.countyID" 
      ng-options="item.countyID as item.county for item in co_option | filter:{ co_state_id : filter.stateID }">
  </select></p>

<p><a href="" id="clear-filter" ng-click="clearFilter()">Reset Filters</a></p>

<div ng-repeat="project in projects | filter:filter">
<div>
  <br>Name: {{ project.name }}
  <br>State: {{project.state}}
  <br>County: {{project.county}}
  <br>
  <span ng-hide="{{project.stateID}} "></span>
  <span ng-hide="{{project.countyID}} "></span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

And a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/webmastersean/4m2d5n8u/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the last parameter of your `filter` to true, see the [comparator parameter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter):

```
<div ng-repeat="project in projects | filter:filter:true">
```

Edit to allow for multiple filters:

```
<input type="text" name="generalSearch" placeholder="Search Project Title" ng-model="filter2.name">

<div ng-repeat="project in projects | filter:filter:true | filter:filter2">
```

Comment: Yep, I thought that would be the answer too, but it breaks the general search because the user can't start typing in a string to filter down the results.... So I guess I should be more specific in my question - I need to filter exactly by state but NOT exactly by the first search field.

Comment: Add another filter or write a custom filter function. I'll modify my answer so that you can filter by both.